# Are IIFEs in JavaScript recursive?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, iife

I am passing a function as an argument to a constructor within an IIFE.  I realize that the outer function of an IIFE is going to be executed, but it appears the function argument is also executed.  I don't really understand why and am wondering how to work around this problem.  Here are two examples:

```
var Foo = function(bar) {
   this.bar = bar;
};
new Foo(function() { console.log("test"); });
```

In the above example, things work as I'd expect. The anonymous function is passed as an argument to the Foo constructor, but is not run.

Here's another example, where it appears an anonymous function that is created within an IIFE is executed, even though it is not explicitly called:

```
(function() { 
   var Foo = function(bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
   };  
   Foo.STATIC_FIELD = new Foo(new function() { console.log("test"); }); 
   return Foo; 
})();
```

In this second example, "test" is written to the console.  I am using the IIFE to protect the global name space from polluting it with Foo.  However, I do not want the function passed to the Foo constructor to be immediately executed.  It's a function I'm holding onto so that it can be later invoked with Foo.STATIC_FIELD.bar();  What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You're calling the anonymous function in the second example by using `new`. Remove the `new` and you'll be golden.

Comment: I flagged this as a typo because I think it is one. Otherwise it's a well-written question.

Comment: Actually I had meant to use new in the first example too. But you're right. I guess my instinct is that I have to use new to create something.  But in this case, you don't create a function using new, you run a function using new.  Kind of odd how "new myFunction" kind of does the same thing as "myFunction()".

Comment: @DavidWhiteman Sort of. It does run the function but it also creates a new object and sets `this` inside of that function to that new object. That's why `new Foo(f)` runs `Foo`, creates a new object, and assigns any properties you want to it by assigning them to `this`. The reason is works with an anonymous function is because technically you can do `new Foo;` and it will create a new `Foo` without passing any arguments to the constructor.

Comment: "Kind of odd how 'new myFunction' kind of does the same thing as 'myFunction()'", yes, you've just stumbled upon a detail of how `new` actually works. It's worth noting that Douglas Crockford avoids using `new` altogether: whether you agree with this is another matter: my point is that it's a tricky concept.

Answer (score -2):

My question was answered sufficiently in the comments by Mike C and DavidS.  If you want to store a function for later invocation, don't use "new" because that will run the function.  Later, be sure to call "call" on that function with the context of the object holding onto the function. For example:

```
foo.myFunction.call(foo);
```

Comment: You know, just doing `foo.myFunction()` would work the same.

Comment: The interpreter will add `()` if you use `new` and fail to add `()` after function